# Some conclusions about string literal and elements number of array, please give your opinion 

Tags: c

From following codes I wrote:

```
#define ELEMENTS_NUMBER_OF(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))


printf("\"abcdef\"[0]: %c\n", "abcdef"[0]);
printf("elements number of \"abcdef\" is %d\n", ELEMENTS_NUMBER_OF("abcdef"));
```

I concluded that:

1. string literal `"abcdef"` is a `char` array;
2. `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` can be used to compute any type array length.

Am I right?

Comment: @AndersK Oblig: http://xkcd.com/138/

Comment: As just an FYI, you should surround the macro definition with parenthesis so that you don't run into order-of-operations issues.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes, if you write "ABC" it can be treated as a string where each character can be accessed with an index although it is not really pretty.
2. if "array" is an array then yes, it will return the number of elements however it the argument is a pointer it will not return correct value since sizeof would return the size of the pointer and not the size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, `"abcdef"` will be stored in a array of type `char` elements and static storage duration.
2. If `a` is an array (even a VLA), `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` computes the number of elements of `a`. `sizeof a` yields the length of the array `a`, in bytes. Take care that if `a` is a pointer to dynamically allocated memory, `sizeof` will yield the pointer type size and also that when applied to a parameter declared to have an array type, `sizeof` yields the size of the respective pointer type.